# Question about the Chandra X-ray Observatory satellite

Tags: support, specific-question, editing

[This question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/64360/what-protocol-does-the-chandra-x-ray-observatory-satellite-use-communicate-with/) is currently closed as needing details of clarity.

What further details need to be added? The question already has an answer, and the answer should still be valid after the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a question is closed, there may be multiple reasons. Sometimes folks will comment, sometimes not. In this case, you have multiple comments:

- Wirelessly. Mostly radio. There are antennae on both the satellite side as well as earth side. Could you make your question more specific. –
- Are you looking for details of radio communication? or the equipment used? or the protocols used? or any other details?
- this question does not show any research effort
- As noted at chandra.harvard.edu/about/spacecraft.html all communication goes through the Deep Space Network. –
- Also note that there will be multiple streams of communication between a satellite and the earth. One omni-directional (low speed) channel for managing the satellite (commands to satellite) and a high speed one for data transfer (astronomical observation data from the satellite in this example). Each channel could use different frequencies, modulation, encoding and different protocols.

So a useful tack to try to get a question reopened is to deal with all the comments, then it will be reviewed in the reopen queue. If you don't deal with the comments, folks will usually vote to remain closed. Currently, you really haven't dealt with many of the comments at all.

Comment: Look at the edit history of the question. I have made made one edit after every comment.

Comment: I'm still not seeing that your question covers all those comments.

Comment: Look at each edit I have made. "Could you make your question more specific. Are you looking for ". I have made it more specific in revision 3. "this question does not show any research effort". Then I have then added a citation in revision 4. "Which satellite? Consider reading through the many, many q&a's on this site about space to ground communication, and then ask a follow-up question. " Then in revision 6, I have changed the question from a general satellite to CXO in particular.

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya from the history of this question, it's pretty apparent that you didn't really have *a question about space exploration*, you just *wanted to ask a question on the space exploration stack*. That doesn't make your question off-topic per se, but it makes it a whole lot less likely that you're going to ask a good one. I note that you have contributed a very small amount to a very large number of stack exchange sites. Considering that you appear to just be counting coup, you've wasted a lot of the community's time.